# Compiling two smart contracts it the same folder cause duplicates

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, solidity-0.8.x, golang

When I compile two contracts in the same folder I get duplicates. The following contracts, Store.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Store {
    event ItemSet(bytes32 key, bytes32 value);
    mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public items;

    constructor() public {}

    function setItem(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) external {
        items[key] = value;
        emit ItemSet(key, value);
    }
}
```

And Store2.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Store2 {
    event ItemSet(bytes32 key, bytes32 value);
    mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public items;

    constructor() public {}

    function setItem(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) external {
        items[key] = value;
        emit ItemSet(key, value);
    }
}
```

When I run

```
docker run -v /mypath/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.0 -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Store2.sol
docker run -v /mypath/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.0 -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Store.sol
abigen --abi=../abi/Store2.abi --bin=../abi/Store2.bin --pkg=api --out=../api/Store2.go
abigen --abi=../abi/Store.abi --bin=../abi/Store.bin --pkg=api --out=../api/Store.go
```

I get **duplicate variables and functions** in the compiled Store.go & Store2.go, both files contain:

```
var ApiMetaData = &bind.MetaData{...}

var ApiABI = ApiMetaData.ABI
func DeployApi(auth *bind.TransactOpts, backend bind.ContractBackend){...}
```

These are just some examples of many duplicates.

How can I compile multiple contracts in the same folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `type` parameter of the `abigen` command to define a custom prefix, for example:

```sh
abigen --abi=../abi/Store2.abi --bin=../abi/Store2.bin --pkg=api --type=Store2 --out=../api/Store2.go
abigen --abi=../abi/Store.abi --bin=../abi/Store.bin --pkg=api --type=Store --out=../api/Store.go
```

The above commands generate variables and functions like the following:

```go
var Store2ABI = Store2MetaData.ABI
var Store2Bin = Store2MetaData.Bin
func DeployStore2(auth *bind.TransactOpts, backend bind.ContractBackend) (common.Address, *types.Transaction, *Store2, error) {...}

...

var StoreABI = StoreMetaData.ABI
var StoreBin = StoreMetaData.Bin
func DeployStore(auth *bind.TransactOpts, backend bind.ContractBackend) (common.Address, *types.Transaction, *Store, error) {...}
```

Why your commands generate the same prefix? The reason is the the default value for `type` is the name of the package. In your case, your commands set the package as `api` (with `--pkg=api`) and so your variables and functions start with the prefix `Api` (`ApiMetaData`, `ApiABI`, etc.).

See `abigen --help` for other interesting parameters (i.e., `alias`):

```sh
❯ abigen --help

NAME:
   abigen - Ethereum ABI wrapper code generator

USAGE:
   abigen [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   1.11.6-stable-ea9e62ca

COMMANDS:
   help, h  Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
    --abi value                   
          Path to the Ethereum contract ABI json to bind, - for STDIN

    --alias value                 
          Comma separated aliases for function and event renaming, e.g. original1=alias1,original2=alias2

    --bin value                   
          Path to the Ethereum contract bytecode (generate deploy method)

    --combined-json value         
          Path to the combined-json file generated by compiler, - for STDIN

    --exc value                   
          Comma separated types to exclude from binding

    --lang value                   (default: "go")
          Destination language for the bindings (go)

    --out value                   
          Output file for the generated binding (default = stdout)

    --pkg value                   
          Package name to generate the binding into

    --type value                  
          Struct name for the binding (default = package name)

   MISC
    --help, -h                     (default: false)
          show help

    --version, -v                  (default: false)
          print the version

COPYRIGHT:
   Copyright 2013-2023 The go-ethereum Authors
```